# or operator does not returns boolean type

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY1fF.png)

i'm now working on if statements

this is my code

a = [1,2,3]
print(4 or 5 in a)

and the outcome is 4 not False

this code returns what i have expected
a = [1,2,3]
print((4 or 5) in a)

I can't understand how or operator works
why the return is integer..? not True or False

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have expression written incorrectly and as a result it evaluates the way it does. What you should have written was:

```
>>> a = [2, 1, 4]
>>> 4 in a or 5 in a
Out[18]: True
```

In your case the expression evaluates only the condition `4 or 5` which evaluates to 4 as the first truthy value.

```
>>> 4 or 5 in a
Out[27]: 4

>>> 4 or 5
Out[28]: 4
```

In fact, variable `a` is completely skipped here and not evaluated at all. We can do the same but using variable `b` **that has never been defined** in this session and we get `4` instead of `UnboundLocalError`:

```
>>> 4 or 5 in b
Out[31]: 4
```

Similarly we can test this behaviour. When you compare two truthy values the result is always the first one the interpreter encounters.

```
>>> 'a' or 'b'
Out[29]: 'a'
>>> 'd' or 'a'
Out[30]: 'd'
```

I suggest reading docs on boolean operators in Python to get a better understanding of what's happening (for example, [here](https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/)). It can get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple conditions in an `if` statement, if the first statement is correct, it doesn't check the second statement. Since 4 is true, it doesn't check if `5` is in the variable `a` or not. Therefore, it returns the value 4 and not False

Comment: This is not how this works. If the interpreter only checked for thuthiness of 4, then you'd just get `True` as the result.

Comment: When I written `4 is true`, I didn't mean it checks truthiness of 4. If we type just `4` in the terminal, it prints `4` and not `true`. In the same way, when you write the statement `4 or 5 in a`, it first checks 4. Since the boolean value of `4` is 1, it doesn't check the second statement and prints `4` just as if we entered the command `4`. To verify this try the command, `4 or False`, you get `4`. Then try the commands  `4 and False` - you get False, `4 and True` -  you get `True`. Since `and` checks both the commands, it returns the boolean type

Comment: This might be a misinterpretation of words, because at least for me this explanation is the same as the same part in the answer from @pavel.